# Camera Intent is called again after finish it in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, camera

I tested on android 4.2 or higher and it don't have bug. But when i test on android 4.1, the Camera Intent is called again after i save image. My flow process in app include:
MainActivity - Fragment - ActivityInfo - Camera 
When i tap camera button on fragment, it start intent (ActivityInfo) and put extra (the name from intent and the name when i choose camera or gallery). After that, ActivityInfo start, and in onCreate function i get value extra and check if it is the name of camera, I will start camera intent. When I done capture photo and save photo, it finish() camera intent and call camera intent again. And this bug appear when i disconnected device with cabe, it disappear while device connect with cabe.

I can't debug because when no problem appear when my device is plugged in. It just have bug when I unplug-in. I have added a line code log message into onCreate of ImageActivity, when the bug appear, I plugin device and do capture and save image, camera finish and log message in onCreate appear on screen debug and Camera appear again.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Please post your code, so that we can fix your bug precisely.

Answer (score 1):

I bet the problem have nothing to do with particular android version, but for other reason:   your activity probably get destroyed and re-created when it returns to be foreground after the image capture. and because you are calling the startActivity() from the onCreate() - it simply runs again.

this is a common mistake:  not handling and taking in cosideration the `saveInstanceState` param indicating if currently the activity/fragment is re-created after system has killed it when it not in foreground because it was under memory pressure.

more information on - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html#RestoreState

code for checking `savedInstanceState`

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. So if you say the memory is a cause, so why I connected device, the bug don't appear.

Comment: I don't know why you don't have the problem when the device is plugged, but I believe that you don't need to waste your time on thinking of that...  The problem is not memory.  The problem is that you are not handling the common situation of temporary memory pressure.   You can verify that this indeed the case by printing toast message within the oncreate() that shows if saved instance state param is null or not.   That way you'll see it with no need to be connected

Comment: Follow http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html and I've done. Save status of activity or every data in onSaveInstanceState function and check it in onCreate function.

Comment: I suggest you to read carfully also this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html